# How does one use the Chromium Embedded Framework from GtkSharp?

Tags: linux, mono, gtk, chromium-embedded

I'm a Microsoft stack developer most familiar with Windows Forms and WPF, but have a need to develop a Linux desktop application that can display some web apps in a modern browser that offers very recent HTML 5, CSS 3, SVG, etc.

I'm thinking GtkSharp running on top of Mono is probably the replacement for WinForms/WPF running on top of .NET which will best leverage what I already know. As for the embedded browser control, I have other requirements strongly advocating CEF over any other solution (although I'm still open to strong suggestions to do otherwise).

Anyone have experience with any of this?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at `CefGlue`, it has a `CefGlue.Demo.GtkSharp` project which would indicate it's possible.

https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/
https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/issues/108/linux-support

Personally I've never used `CefGlue` so I cannot say more than I've seen in passing.